# How can i remove border-right on last column on each row in a Grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

In the code below i would like to remove `border-right` from div 4 and 8.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  row-gap: 1rem;
}

.container div{
  padding: 1rem;
  border-right: 1px solid red;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e6u3skz2/5/

Answer (score 2):

You mean like this?

`border-right:0;` or background color

```
.container div:nth-child(4n) {
  border-right: 1px solid white;
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  row-gap: 1rem;
}

.container div {
  padding: 1rem;
  border-right: 1px solid red;
  height: 50px;
}

.container div:nth-child(4n) {
  border-right: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Or you could just `border-right: 0`, right?